# Find best combination from a matrix

Tags: matrices

I have got the following matrix:

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F
A 1  0  2  6  0  5
B 9  0  1  4  10 8
C 3  3  0  5  7  9
D 9  10 15 2  0  1
E 10 10 0  5  1  4
```

There are 5 rows (A-E) and 6 columns (A-F)

You can choose only one value from a row, for example AD=6. You have to choose a value from every row.

Is there any way to get the best combination from this matrix? The best combination is where the sum of the chosen coordinates is the maximal possible? I need the coordinates at the end too.

**Edit**

The rule is, that there should be no property (columns are properties) with value=0. The sum of all properties should be the max possible sum of all combinations.

I tried to implement some algorithms, but its a kind of 3D Matrix at the end.

There are plenty of possible combinations:

```
[AA, BA, CA, DA, EA], [AB, BB, CB, DB, EB], [AC, BC, CC, DC, EC]...
[AB, BA, CA, DA, EA], [AC, BA, CA, DA, EA], [AD, BA, CA, DA, EA]...
.
.
.
```

Comment: Are you missing a condition that you can only choose an element from a row and a given column i.e if you chose AD, you can no longer choose a value from the column D. Since the former will just be the max of each row. ps if you want help, you should also provide some initial attempts.

Comment: The problem is you are only limited to the rows. so you could for example choose the value from the D column but in the B row, or any other row but not in A. And you can only choose AD. You cannot choose AD and AC

Comment: so why can't one just choose the maximum value in each row since the sum will surely be the global max sum.

Comment: because it is not a precise solution i think. There are rows with many equal values. The matrix from above is just an example.

Comment: can you specify the rules? because as your problem in state, you only need to choose the max value from each row

Comment: @N.Zukowski The sum will be one value from each row. So, any sum of values from each row will be less than or equal to the sum of the maximum values from each row. What do you mean that this is not a precise solution? How could you get any more precise?